# Trying to fix text input layout widget in horizontal orientation

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying to fix TextInputLayout widget horizontally with parent layout as **Linear Layout**.

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/phone_code"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:text="+91"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:hint="@string/phone_code"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:inputType="none">

                    <requestFocus />

                </EditText>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginNo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minWidth="200dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:hint="@string/msg_enter_mobile"
                android:digits="1234567890+"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:inputType="phone">

                <requestFocus />

            </EditText>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Now this widget has `request focus` when it focuses on view this hint moves upward giving me space to write in edit text earlier when I had `single edittext` it was working fine but now this hint is `hidden` I can't see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `TextInputLayout` `layout_gravity` from both ones and it will work:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            //layout_gravity removed
            >
```

[image]

> Error View

As mentioned on my comment, Look the image 1) `android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"` caused the view to go inside the toolbar, 2) After avoiding the gravity ( I removed the gravity because I didn't wanted to mislead your bottommargin).

[image]

Comment: Worked ...but tell me why it was happening on just adding another edit text?

Comment: Sorry, Office meetings. 1.) gravity for `TextInputlayout` took the hint inside the toolbar which caused by your lineralayout `wrap_content`. 2.) Avoid hard coding your `layout_marginBottom="50dp"` for `TextInputLayout` which also responsible for problem no. 1. 3) Avoid hard coding 4.) I removed the gravity because I didn't wanted to mislead your bottommargin.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following: width 0dp and weight of 1 for both elements. You can specify weight according to the space you want element to occupy, use weight of 2 for one of the elements and you will note the difference. Hope it helps.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/phone_code"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:text="+91"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:maxLength="5"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:hint="@string/phone_code"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:inputType="none">

                    <requestFocus />

                </EditText>
```

Comment: I know how to use weight property but my problem is already resolved see verified answer

Answer (score 0):

Change width of both TextInputLayout to 0dp and add weight =1 in them.
You can then also change width of EditText to match_parent